# Inbound traffic equals outbound traffic

Tags: ubuntu, networking, traffic, cacti

I'm trying to monitor inbound and outbound traffic using Cacti on Ubuntu Server 14.04.1. I've got it up and running, but the reported data is wrong. When I run 'ifconfig' I get the following:

```
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:84132 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:84132 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:6698322 (6.6 MB)  TX bytes:6698322 (6.6 MB)

p3p1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr d0:50:99:28:ab:91
          inet addr:192.168.1.100  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::d250:99ff:fe28:ab91/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:19
```

As you can see, all the traffic is going through the loopback interface and the outbound bytes are the same as the inbound bytes. I am not familiar with linux, so I don't know if this is the intended behavior, but it doesn't seem right to me.

Comment: p3p1 is belong to p2p interface.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: What does Cacti show to cause you to think it is wrong? Inbound and outbound should always be equal on `lo` because that is the loopback interface and can only talk to itself.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. Is there any way through which I can see the real RX and TX bytes. [This](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d2/Mrtg95.png) is what I would like to get, and [this](http://i.imgur.com/zYog8db.png) is what I'm getting.

Comment: Also, I have transferred 100MB from an offsite location and lo is now at 6.7 MB at p3p1 at 0. It seems like traffic is not being recorded.